# querying data from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Following is my JS code

```
$("#submitPassword").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("IsUserExist","Register")",
                    data: { emailOrPhone: $("#emailOrPhone").val(), password: $("#password").val() },
                    success:function(response){
                        if (response) {
                            alert("User Exist");
                        }
                        else alert("Doesn't exist");
                    }
                });
            });
```

And following is Controller side code

```
public bool IsUserExist(string emailOrPhone,string password)
        {
            DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
            var q = from profile in db.Profiles
                    where profile.Email == emailOrPhone && profile.Password == password
                    select profile;
            if (q == null)
                return false;
            else
                return true;

        }
```

I am program is always showing an alert box i.e. "User Exist", even if i enter incorrect password.
Please tell me what is problem

Comment: Code in IsUserExist is of entity framework

Comment: No no no no ***NO!!*** This can only work if the password in stored plain text. Where is your salt and hash?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no results, the expression will still return an empty enumerator. It won't return null. You need to look at the *count* of how many results, and check that it's at least one.

## You also need to stop storing passwords in plain text.

If you only want to know if a user exists, just look up the user name. If you actually want to log them in, you need to look up or calculate the salt for that particular user, use that salt and password to generate a hash code (with a *secure* hashing algorithm... md5 doesn't count), and then compare that with the value stored in your password field. When a user sets or changes their password, you use the same process to save the new value. Anything else is horribly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for change response to response.data in your if condition

```
                         success:function(response){
                        if (response.data) {
                            alert("User Exist");
                        }
                        else alert("Doesn't exist");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare response to strings in your JavaScript:

```
if (response == "True") {
     alert("User Exist");
} else if(response == "False") {...
```

Because bool controller return "False" or "True" which, I bet, are treated as strings by JavaScript, so response will always be defined and true.

Next time try debugging: first, your controller - if "q" is null, then it returns null. So easy conclusion that problem is with JavaScript. Debug JS, atleast with console.log(response) and you would have figured how to change your `if` statement.